# How to create an array of linked lists in c?

Tags: arrays, c, linked-list, queue

I haven't used C in a while so I'm confused by the syntax of how to create an array of linked lists in C.
I have a linked list structure called "Node" and I want my array to consist of 50 separate linked lists initiated to NULL. I want to be able to do something like use array[0] to add and remove information to the first list, array[1] to add and remove from the 2nd list, and so on. Sorry if this info isn't very helpful, let me know if you need more details.

Comment: One way: `Node *list_array[50];`. Then use a `for` loop to init each element to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to create a static array:

```
struct node {
    // Your data
    struct node* next;
};
typedef struct node Node;

int main()
{
    Node* array[50];

    // Your code
}
```

Initializing can be done using a simple `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
    array[i] = NULL;
}
```

Comment: `Node* array[50] = { 0 };` is sufficient for the initialization. The for-loop isn't needed.